# What does this achievement I have been told have achieved mean?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash

"If you wish to discourse  with me you must define your terms."--Voltaire. I have been told that I  have earned the "Where In The World ?" hat, that it is a secret hat, with an option to "show controls". What does any of this mean?

Comment: Might be better in the meta?

Comment: This belongs on one of the meta boards (Winter Bash might have a meta itself, not sure).  At any rate, the hat means that you were active on the site on December 21.

Comment: The [thread here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288271/winter-bash-2016-all-hats) on big Meta has details about hats. And the page on [Winter bash](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com) in general.